# Destructuring different types in JS

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

For an object `x`

```
const x = {
 a: 'foo',
 b: () => { return 'bar' )
}
```

Is it possible to destructure `x` to get both `a` and `b` as strings in a single step?

```
{a, <something with b?>} = x
console.log(a, b) // 'foo bar'
```

On a broader scope, I am confused on how to cleanly destructure different types contained within a single object

In the real world, `a` is an invocation and `b` is a nested object

```
const x = {
 a: c(), // returns an object
 b: {
   x: {...},
   y: () => {...}
 } // is an object
}

// is this even doable
{< some magic stuff >} = x
typeof a === typeof b //true
```

Comment: Destructuring cannot call functions.

Comment: Destructuring assignments is exclusively intended for regular objects and arrays, not for exotic objects. Moreover, destructuring neither includes an implicit nor an explicit type conversion. The type of the assigned value and the type of the corresponding object property are always the same. It is a mechanical process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, that's only possible with [property getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) if that is an option:

```js
const x = {
 a: 'foo',
 get b() { return 'bar' }
}

const {a, b} = x
console.log(a, b) // 'foo bar'
```

Comment: This was not the answer I expected, but it works. And while I was hesitant at first, using getters actually improved the overall structure of my module. Thanks!